# How do I change my interval within the function itself?

Tags: javascript, function, time, draw, intervals

So, this is the code I'm using to set my interval which triggers draw() every 0.1s

```
var intervalTime = 100;
setInterval(draw, intervalTime);
function draw() {
    if( i == 1 ) intervalTime = 50;
}
```

I want to know how I can change that intervalTime to 50 when i becomes 1. The code above doesn't seem to work like that. It stays at an interval time of 0.1s

Comment: Use setTimeout instead, to call the function and then inside the function itself. Especially for small intervals and if your function takes quite a bit of time this method is better, because it ensures that there's at least X millisec. between the calls. The only potential benefit of setInterval could be (but isn't!) that it really calls the function at those specified points in time, but in reality it only puts them in the queue so no benefit, only disadvantages. I recommend against setInterval altogether, personally. How timers work: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: or clear the interval and recreate it

Comment: Once the interval speed is passed to the function, you can't change it, so one of the above solutions in the comments is the only way.

Comment: Clearing the interval and creating a new one after one run should instead be done by using setTimeout from the start. It isn't really an interval when you remove it again each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var intervalTime = 100;
var interval = setInterval(draw, intervalTime);

function draw() {
    if( i == 1 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(draw, intervalTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use setInterval when you really only call it once. Go with setTimeout right away, no need to clear an interval and less confusing (when reading through lots of code a year later and it says "interval").